# How can I install cython using cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cython

I want to install cython with help of cygwin. But in cygwin I found many errors regarding header file.
I already install python in Cygwin.

Comment: Please tell us what you're doing and add the logs to the post.

Comment: What errors are you finding?

Comment: I found errors regarding header file (missing or wrong format).

Comment: Actually I want to create .so file from python source using gcc compiler. So, I can use it as a shared library

Answer (score 0):

Do not use cygwin, per [documentation](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a better-late-than-never answer though I just managed to install it. In the Cygwin installer mark for installation the following items:

1. `python2`
2. `python2-pip`
3. `python2-devel`

Also possible to change `python2` to `python3`. I also installed (don't know if necessary):

4. `gcc-core`
5. `gcc-g++`
6. `cygwin-devel`

Hopefully I didn't forget anything. After completion of the installation, run the Cygwin terminal, and in there run:

- `pip2 install --upgrade pip`
- `pip2 install --upgrade wheel`
- `pip2 install Cython`

And you're done.